# How many candles are in the box?

Tags: math

For the holiday currently described as [ck]?hann?ukk?ah? or thereabouts, 1 candle is lit on the first day, increasing up to a final 8 candles on day 8.  However, there is an extra candle each day that is used to light the others.

So, when you buy that box in the store, how many candles do you get?

Comment: OK Jon, what's the formula for a triagular number, and who discovered it?

Comment: Jon, why not just retag this as code golf? I think it is a valid programming excercise.

Comment: I am for the re-opening of this question as a programming excercise.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://judaism.about.com/cs/chanukahgeneral/ht/hol_chan_light.htm) your menorah needs to have 8 candles plus the extra one you use to light the other candles with.  Most of the sites I found had packs of 45 Chanukah candles.  (MAN!  Am I bored while working on Christmas Eve or WHAT?)

Comment: I purposely left it open to see the variety I got.  It's really about the math quiz, though.

Comment: wow! @perryneal was able to answer with 1 of reputation! I still see it as closed!